# Bouncycastle certificate - troubles to import somewhere

Tags: java, openssl, certificate, bouncycastle, pkcs#12

I generated a self-signed certificate and private key in pkcs12 format using bouncycastle (code below). It works properly (I can view it in OS or in openssl), except 1 very important thing - i can import it nowhere. Thunderbird, Chromium, Evolution they all give an error - failed for unknown reason. I checked it on few OS'es - all the same. But here's some trick - if I convert my pkcs12(A) to pem and after this pem to pkcs12(B) using openssl (openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -out client.pem) - it changes in size and I can import it. What's wrong with my code?

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    kpGen.initialize(1024, random);
    KeyPair keyPair = kpGen.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey RSAPubKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    PrivateKey RSAPrivateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    X500Name subjectDN = new X500Name("C=BY,O=Self-Signed,CN =" + domain);
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo pubKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(ASN1Sequence.getInstance(RSAPubKey.getEncoded()));
    X509v3CertificateBuilder v3CertBuild;
    v3CertBuild = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(subjectDN,
            BigInteger.valueOf(new SecureRandom().nextInt()),
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10)),
            subjectDN,
            pubKeyInfo);
    DigestCalculator digCalc = new BcDigestCalculatorProvider().get(new AlgorithmIdentifier(OIWObjectIdentifiers.idSHA1));
    X509ExtensionUtils x509ExtensionUtils = new X509ExtensionUtils(digCalc);
    v3CertBuild.addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, x509ExtensionUtils.createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(pubKeyInfo));
    v3CertBuild.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, x509ExtensionUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(pubKeyInfo));
    v3CertBuild.addExtension(MiscObjectIdentifiers.netscapeCertType,
            false, new NetscapeCertType(NetscapeCertType.smime));
    v3CertBuild.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment));
    ASN1EncodableVector purposes = new ASN1EncodableVector();
    purposes.add(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_emailProtection);
    v3CertBuild.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(false));
    v3CertBuild.addExtension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, new DERSequence(purposes));
    GeneralName[] genNames = new GeneralName[1];
    genNames[0] = new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, new DERIA5String(domain));
    v3CertBuild.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, false, new GeneralNames(genNames));
    ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(RSAPrivateKey);
    X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(v3CertBuild.build(sigGen));
    certificate.verify(RSAPubKey);
    certificate.checkValidity(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier bagAttr = (PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier) certificate;
    bagAttr.setBagAttribute(
            PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_friendlyName,
            new DERBMPString(domain));
    KeyStore kstore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
    X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];
    chain[0] = certificate;
    kstore.load(null, null);
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream("Certificates/" + domain + ".p12");
    PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier bagAttr1 = (PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier) RSAPrivateKey;
    bagAttr1.setBagAttribute(
            PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_friendlyName,
            new DERBMPString(domain));
    bagAttr1.setBagAttribute(
            PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_localKeyId,
            new SubjectKeyIdentifier(RSAPubKey.getEncoded()));
    kstore.setKeyEntry(domain, RSAPrivateKey, null, chain);
    kstore.store(fOut, password.toCharArray());
```

Comment: I read this question this morning and just read it again... Its not clear to me what the problem is. Would you clearly state the problem you are having or what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jww Sorry, maybe it's beacause my English... Chromium or other browsers, Thunderbird or other mail clients support importing certificates (it can be self-signed or enother) to encrypt\decrypt messages for example. I generated my own self-signed certificate with code in my post. I can't import it. It's well-working certificate, i almost sure about that, i can do anything i want with it. Except importing, i can't underdand why, and i need help...